# Raising reflected event causes error: "Object does not match target type"

Tags: .net, events, reflection

I have a need to be able to raise events from outside a class so I thought Reflection is the solution. However, after having retrieved the event's `MultiCastDelegate` and its invocation method I cannot invoke it. When I do I get a `TargetException` with the message "Object does not match target type".

Here's some code to reproduce the problem:

A helper class:

```
public static class Reflection
{
    public static MethodInfo GetEventMethod(this object obj, string eventName, out Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("eventName");

        var mcDelegate = getEventMulticastDelegate(obj, eventName, out targetType);
        return mcDelegate != null ? mcDelegate.Method : null;
    }

    private static MulticastDelegate getEventMulticastDelegate(object obj, string eventName, out Type targetType)
    {
        // traverse inheritance tree looking for the specified event ...
        targetType = obj.GetType();
        while (true)
        {
            var fieldInfo = targetType.GetField(eventName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetField);
            if (fieldInfo != null)
                return fieldInfo.GetValue(obj) as MulticastDelegate;

            if (targetType.BaseType == null)
                return null;

            targetType = targetType.BaseType;
        }
    }

    public static void RaiseEvent(this object obj, string eventName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        Type targetType;
        var methodInfo = obj.GetEventMethod(eventName, out targetType);
        if (methodInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("eventName", string.Format("Cannot raise event \"{0}\". Event is not supported by {1}", eventName, obj.GetType()));

        var targetObj = obj;
        if (targetType != obj.GetType())
            targetObj = obj.ConvertTo(targetType);

        methodInfo.Invoke(targetObj, parameters);  // *** ERROR HERE ***
    }
}
```

And some code to test it:

```
[TestClass]
public class Reflection
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void RaiseReflectedEvent()
    {
        var bar = new Bar();
        var isRaised = false;
        bar.TestEvent += (sender, args) => isRaised = true;
        bar.RaiseEvent("TestEvent", this, new EventArgs());
        Assert.IsTrue(isRaised);
        var foo = new Foo();
        isRaised = false;
        foo.TestEvent += (sender, args) => isRaised = true;
        foo.RaiseEvent("TestEvent", this, new EventArgs());
        Assert.IsTrue(isRaised);
    }

    private class Bar
    {
        public event EventHandler TestEvent;
    }

    private class Foo : Bar
    {
    }
}
```

I must've missed something but I'm currently out of clues and would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, it must be said that this is very bad design. Event invocations are restricted on purpose. Impersonating an object and raising its event without its consent is breaking all kinds of assumptions on both the event owner and the any events listeners. You should never ever do this in production code.

Second, the approach you're taking doesn't work in general. Events don't have to have a field associated with them, and that field doesn't have to have the same name as the event. The following is valid C#:

```
class Foo {
    public event EventHandler Bar { add { } remove { } }
}
```

(this form is typically used to redirect one event to another)

Third, as a corollary to the above, even if you find the field, that may not be the proper way to invoke the event. In certain languages (such as C++/CLI), an event can be explicitly associated with a `Raise` method which raises the event. Calling the delegate without going through the `Raise` method could be a serious logical error.

**However** ... if you choose to ignore all of the very strong reasons to not do this, here's the problem with your code:

A `Delegate` is not just a method reference. It's a method reference *and* the context needed to invoke the method.

Say you have the following code:

```
class Foo {
    void Bar() { }
    static void Main() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Action action = new Action(foo.Bar);
    }
}
```

`action.Method` will be a reference to `Foo.Bar`, while `action.Target` will be `foo`. In your `GetEventMethod` function you are throwing away the target! The delegate knows what object to pass as the '`this`' parameter to the method, but you are ignoring it. In fact, in your case, since you are using the lambda expression `bar.TestEvent += (sender, args) => isRaised = true;` the '`this`' argument will be a compiler-generated closure object. The only way you could hope to have a reference to that object is through the `Target` object on the delegate.

So the problem is you're trying to re-implement the `Delegate` class, but you're not doing it as well. Just call [DynamicInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx) on the delegate instance itself.

Except of course, don't do that, because don't do any of this. Event invocations are private to the type that defines them (unless that type chooses to expose them). If it was meant to be otherwise, the type would have just exposed a `Delegate`-typed property.

Comment: Thanks for this brilliant explanation. I won't argue the quality of the design. I do realize it's fragile but I'm mainly experimenting and have no plans on using this to call anyone else's code with it. I would argue that once you start walking down "reflection lane" your gonna step on quite a few smelly ones.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a situation where I had to raise an event from a derived class and even though using Reflection here is not the best design, it enabled me to resolve an issue and meet a deadline so I thought I'd pass it along.

The code below is somewhat modified from the working code but should still serve as a good basis for implementing a similar solution in your own project.

```
protected void RaiseReflectedEvent( string eventName, params object[] args )
{

    var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

    var eventField =
        this.GetType()
        .GetField( eventName, bindingFlags );

    if( eventField != null )
    {

        var eventDelegate = eventField.GetValue( this );
        if( eventDelegate != null )
        {
            ( (Delegate)eventDelegate ).DynamicInvoke( args );
        }

    }

}
```